# count of company for each employee

Tags: sql

How can I get a count of same company for each employee
Empid Company

1     A
2     A
3     A
4     B
5     B
so empid 1,2 and 3 should show count of 3 and empid 4 and 5 should show count of 2.
I counted the items for group before ie... count number of customers for company using
select company, count(empid)
from employee
group by company
but having hard time counting group for items(counting same company for each empid)
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a new column, use a window function:

```
select t.*, count(*) over (partition by company) as employees_in_company
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select emp_id,comp from emp_cmp group by emp_id,comp;
+--------+------+
| emp_id | comp |
+--------+------+
|      1 | A    |
|      1 | c    |
|      2 | A    |
|      2 | b    |
|      2 | c    |
|      3 | a    |
|      3 | c    |
+--------+------+

select emp_id,comp,count(comp) from emp_cmp group by emp_id;
+--------+------+-------------+
| emp_id | comp | count(comp) |
+--------+------+-------------+
|      1 | A    |           2 |
|      2 | A    |           3 |
|      3 | c    |           2 |
+--------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: Hi, thats not giving a count.  I need for empid 1 to show count of 3, empid 2 to show count of 3, empid 3 to show count of 3 since they all share company A, empid 4 to show count of 2 and empid 5 to show count of 2 since they all share company B... thanks

Comment: Hi, "grop by emp_id" gives error message "not a GROP BY expression" I think you meant "group by emp_id, comp" which gets rid of the error but the results are count of 1 for every record